# Use File_Get_Contents to grab site, then remove header and display site?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

In the below code, I've tried using the file get contents command to get the website content and output it, and but its showing a blank page when I run it.

```
<html>
<?php 

$site = "http://facebook.com";
echo $file_get_contents[$site];

?>

<html>
```

After this, I wanted to use

```
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
```

or something similar to edit the header but the first code to display the webpage wasn't working so what would be the mistake?

Comment: **$**file_get_contents ? It may be a typo, he ?

Comment: Looks to me like you are echoing an array value, not calling a _function_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work but i guess it requires some sort of SSL or something else,  see more about [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) because

> file_get_contents() — Reads entire file into a string

As it a **function** not an array as you used in your code.

```
<?php 
$site = "http://facebook.com";
echo file_get_contents($site); // remove $ from file_get_contents() function
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is `file_get_contents()`.  It's a function - you're calling it as a hash variable. Just a syntax issue.  See correct usage below:

```
<html>
<?php 

$site = "http://facebook.com";
echo file_get_contents($site);

?>
<html>
```

Read the file_get_contents documentation for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Two points to change. 
1. Remove the $ in front of file_get_content() because its a function.
2. Since it is a function the parameters is feed using () not [] which means an array and next time please try and post the error message to, it would help quickly see the problem with the code;

```
<html>
<?php 

$site = "http://facebook.com";
echo file_get_contents($site);

?>

<html>
```

3. Adding  `header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');` would allow you load the page into an iframe as you desired.